# Angular If Condition in component not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular6

I'm trying to set angular model values based on the id property.
If "id" has a value get data from service, else set default values

```
ngOnInit() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:radix
    let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.departmentId = id;

    if (id === NaN) {
       // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
       this.departmentModel = new Department(1, 0, '', 'admin', new Date(2018, 11, 11), 'localhost', 'admin', new Date(2018, 11, 11), 'localhost');
    } else {
       this.departmentService.getDepartment(this.departmentId).subscribe(data => this.departmentModel = data);        
    }
}
```

But it always goes to the else part, even though "id" has a value. 
How do I solve this. Any help would be highly appriciated.

Comment: try ```if(id)```.

Comment: @FatemeFazli will create a false positive with `id === 0`. OP, please provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking if something is `NaN` should be done with the native function `isNaN`.

`if(isNaN(id))`

On a side note, I think your logic is reversed though, since your service call wont work if it's `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate reply. It works. I have updated the logic also.